# Can you display both an image and some text in a single tkinter label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a loading bar in tkinter, that has several different images to make the loading bar look like it is animated. The production bar also has some text showing how long it has left.

The problem is that because text must have a background, which ruins the look of the loading bar. So I made background images for the text. However, I realised that labels cannot have both images (background pictures) and text (seconds left).

Is there a way to allow labels to have images and text? Thank you.

Defining Percent0Data:

```
TimeDisplay0Data = PhotoImage(file = os.getcwd()+"/appdata/TimeDisplay0.png")
```

Defining loading bar:

```
ProductionBar1 = Label(Main,image=Percent0Data,bd=0)
ProductionBar1.place(x=60,y=140)
```

Setting the text:

```
LabelProductionTime1.config(text=str(TimeLeftRelic1).ljust(5,"0")+"s")
```

Setting the background image:

```
ProductionBar1.config(image=Percent0Data)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to specify `compound` parameter to be one of the options:
`tk.LEFT, tk.RIGHT, tk.CENTER, tk.BOTTOM, tk.TOP`

minimal example:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = Tk()

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'imgpath')) 

Label(root, text='Hello', image=image, compound='center').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! Which type of `compound` is best to use?

Comment: @SamuelMay there is nothing as best. It depends on which one you want to use.